# How to change the html contents depending upon which button on the page is pressed

Tags: javascript, html

When the "more" buttons are pressed on the page, a pop up modal appears with content inside of the modal. I want the text inside of the modal to change depending upon which button is pressed.

When I press the button "link" I want the html code with the header "one" to be inserted. When I press the linkTwo button I want the html code with the header "two" to be inserted. However, when I press either button all the HTML is inserted. How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```js
const link = document.querySelector('#subheader--link');
const linkTwo = document.querySelector('#subheader--link--two');
const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
const learnContainer = document.querySelector('.learned__container');

class App {
  constructor() {
    link.addEventListener('click', this._openModal.bind(this));
    linkTwo.addEventListener('click', this._openModal.bind(this));
    this._renderList();
  }

  _openModal() {
    overlay.classList.remove('hide--overlay');
    learnContainer.classList.add('appear');
  }

  _renderList(e) {
    if (e.target === link)
      learnContainer.innerHTML +=
      ` 
          <h1 class="learned--header">One</h1>
          <ul id="list">
            <li id="list--item">One</li>
            <li id="list--item">One</li>
            <button id="close--one">Close</button>
          </ul>
        `
    if (e.target === linkTwo)
      learnContainer.innerHTML +=
      ` 
          <h1 class="learned--header">Two</h1>
          <ul id="list">
            <li id="list--item">Two</li>
            <li id="list--item">TWo</li>
            <button id="close--one">Close</button>
          </ul>
        `
  }
}

const app = new App
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p id="title--header">Projects</p>
  <div class="slide--in timeline__container">
    <div class="subheader__container">
      <h1 id="subheader">Dymez Media</h1>
      <button id="subheader--link">More</button>
    </div>

    <p id="timeline--paragraph">
      Created this website for a photographer in Booklyn, New York. This was created using HMTL, CSS, and JavaScript. I packaged the code using Parcel, and deployed the site on Netlify with a custom domain that was purchased on Squarespace. The photos on the
      site were organized on the page using grid; making it easy to create media queries for browser resizing. Intersection Observers were used to have the images slowly fade in and have text move up into the viewport.<br><br> Visit site: <a href="https://dymezmedia.com/">here</a>
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <p id="title--header"></p>
    <div class="slide--in timeline__container">
      <div class="subheader__container">
        <h1 id="subheader">Mapty</h1>
        <button id="subheader--link--two">More</button>
      </div>

      <p id="timeline--paragraph">
        Created this website for as a project in the JavaScript course that I completed. This website uses an API from leafty to add a map to the viewport based upon the users location. Core functionality of the site was coded in a JavaScript class, in order
        to make code neat and to utilize constructor functions to excute particular tasks on page load. Three other JavaScript classes were created called Workout, Running, and Cycling. The Running and Cycling classes are extended from the Workout class
        to apply prototypal inheritance and avoid having to write duplicate code. <br><br> Visit site: <a href="https://javascriptcourse-mapty.netlify.app/">here</a> (compatible only with computers)
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="hide--learn learned__container"> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: When I click either link or linkTwo all of the html code is inserted. @code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link` and `linkTwo` both exist on the DOM at all times.  You are asking the if statement if they exist.  Since they do exist, both conditional statements are being met.

To resolve, pass in the event object to renderList and put that into your if statements:

```
_renderList(e) {
  if (e.target === link) {
    // open link 1 
  }

  if(e.target === linkTwo) {
    //open link 2
  }
}
```

You will be able to differentiate between the two buttons like this.

###### Full refactor of the class

```
class App {
  constructor() {
    link.addEventListener('click', this._openModal);
    linkTwo.addEventListener('click', this._openModal);
  }

  _openModal(e) {
    overlay.classList.remove('hide--overlay');
    learnContainer.classList.add('appear');

    if (e.target === link)
      learnContainer.innerHTML +=
        ` 
          <h1 class="learned--header">One</h1>
          <ul id="list">
            <li id="list--item">One</li>
            <li id="list--item">One</li>
            <button id="close--one">Close</button>
          </ul>
        `
    if (e.target === linkTwo)
      learnContainer.innerHTML +=
        ` 
          <h1 class="learned--header">Two</h1>
          <ul id="list">
            <li id="list--item">Two</li>
            <li id="list--item">TWo</li>
            <button id="close--one">Close</button>
          </ul>
        `
  }
}
```

Comment: What code goes in the if statements in the _openModal(e)? I need to use only one container holding the html, and update the innerHtml depending on which button is pressed. I found that if I use two containers holding the separate html, I am unable to close the modal due to layering issues @PsiKai

Comment: openModal was the wrong function, I meant to say renderLIst, that was my mistake, and I edited my answer

Comment: it says cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

Comment: Right, it will take more code changes than just my code to fix the issue.  I'll make one more update.

Comment: I updated my JavaScript code in my question to what I currently have after your suggested changes, does this look like what you meant?

Comment: This works I appreciate the help. Will definitely remember this concept going forward. I now see why you need to use the event object.